# Javascript hide/show toggle works both ways in Opera, but only one way in other browsers

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, opera, transition

I have a customized show/hide toggle script that I'm using along with CSS3 transitions for the effects.

The script shows the  content when clicked, and hides it when the 'HideLink' link is clicked, complete with CSS3 transistions - but only in Opera.

In other browsers the script only works for showing the content, clicking the hide link doesn't work.

See this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xte63/

Comment: OK, this is strange. When I was working on the Fiddle it failed in Chrome when hiding. The problem is that the code fails when used in my HTML. I have the script and CSS in the <head>.

Comment: @Derek The page is reloading instead of triggering the hide function on my Nightly 16. @ OP I guess you're using too much code for something so simple..

Comment: It works if I don't use CSSText for styling the JS and use '.style.display', but I wanted to add more CSS strings in one line and didn't know of another way.

Comment: A more easy way to toggle hide/show is by using HTML5: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/zGFNF/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Know any method for non-HTML5 browsers (which would be able to be styled with CSS3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days with show / hide javascript, I prefer to use HTML5's data-* attributes.

This can already be used in non-HTML5 browsers via the getAttribute and setAttribute function.

I've quickly tried it against IE7, Chrome and Opera and it seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ThJcb/

```
function showHide(shID) {
    var exDiv = document.getElementById(shID);
    if(exDiv.getAttribute("data-visible") != 'false'){
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.cssText = ';height:auto;opacity:1;visibility:visible;';  
         document.getElementById(shID).style.cssText = ';height:0;opacity:0;visibility:hidden;';  
         exDiv.setAttribute("data-visible" , 'false');
    } else { 
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.cssText = ';height:;opacity:0;visibility:hidden;';  
         document.getElementById(shID).style.cssText = ';height:auto;opacity:1;visibility: visible ;';   
          exDiv.setAttribute("data-visible" , 'true'); 
    }
}
```

This allows you to determine the state of the div without having to check for CSS values.

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, a typo was on the hide link (onlick instead of onclick) which made it appear the above jsfiddle worked whereas it didn't. At least not exactly as I made an error in the logic, setting the "data-visible" to false instead of true.

Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThJcb/4/
(javascript snippet above updated also)

Comment: The script has the problem of reloading the page when the 'Hide Content' link is clicked, see this updated JSFiddle with a body margin (scroll down to the link, click it to see what I mean): http://jsfiddle.net/ThJcb/1/

Comment: Update: The script was reloading the page because the 'Hide Content' link had a 'onlick' not 'onclick' function, which made it seem like the script was working, when in fact it didn't :( See this updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThJcb/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. The code works beautifully in JSFiddle.  Unfortunately when I tested it in my HTML it doesn't load. I think it's because in JSFiddle the 'Framework' is set to 'No Wrap (head)' - any suggestions for tweaking it to work with OnLoad?

Comment: Without looking at the HTML, it would be hard to see why the above isn't working. Could be another Javascript error, Javascript not being set properly, HTML markup being incorrect.

Comment: I have the JS and CSS inline in the <head>. See the markup from this pastebin in a HTML test page (http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/html/f_testbed.html) to check in Chrome/Opera: http://pastebin.com/Mnp0jVs7

Comment: The script on the testbed works on Opera 12.00. Chrome seems to be broken due to a security reason (script detected in the request). Have you tried it in a normal html file?

Comment: Well, it's a mystery. I have it working (finally). The pastebin code (when copied from the top section) works, oddly, while the original 'raw' pastebin data (copied from the JSFiddle) seemed to fail.

Well, anyway, it's working thanks to your efforts!